# Tag suggestions do not appear while inline editing

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, inline-editor

When I inline edit a question, I do not see tag suggestions as I type in the tag box.  Can someone look into this?

I am using Firefox 5 on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

**Edit:** The error console returned the following error:

```
Error: bindTagFilterAutoComplete is not defined
Source File: http://superuser.com/questions/308771/why-are-we-still-using-cpus-instead-of-gpus
Line: 2
```

Note that the above URL is only one page where I experienced the problem; it occurs on all pages that I attempt to retag.

**Edit 2:** An image of the problem:

[image: Missing tag suggestions while inline editing]

I've updated to Firefox 5.0.1, but the problem persists. Anyone else running Firefox 5 with this issue?

Comment: I see them on Chrome 12 Dev Mode, now going to test on FF6

Comment: it works on FF6

Comment: Non-repro on Opera 10.63 - Cleared your cache?

Comment: Do you have firebug installed? Can you check if `tageditor.js` is ever loaded?

Comment: Firebug is not installed.

Comment: Although I can't reproduce this, I have a theory -- please test this for me: After you have started inline editing and confirmed that tag autocomplete is broken, put `javascript:void(bindTagFilterAutoComplete('#tagnames'))` into your location bar and check if works then.

Comment: The above code worked, and autocomplete appears to be the issue.

Comment: @DragonLord: I don't understand -- Can you confirm that tag suggestions did *not* work before you pasted that code, but *did* work aftwerwards?

Comment: Doing it again failed.  The loading animation (at the right end of the input box) appears for a split second, but nothing else appears.

Comment: Can you try if it works now, please?

Comment: @balpha, the tag autocomplete now works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect a timing issue between the loading and execution of JavaScript files. We've seen issues like this previously; they are hard to reproduce reliably across machines.

In addition, this particular autocomplete issue would only appear for non-moderators between 2000 and 2999 reputation (you fall into these boundaries on Super User, as does another user on Webmasters who [reported the same issue](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/525/tag-auto-complete-no-longer-works-on-question-edit-for-main-site)).

So while this is indeed [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), it's plausible; we'll have a look at trying to avoid these timing issues.

**Update:** We've made a change to how the JavaScript is loaded, and since you report it's working now, I guess my suspicion was right.

Comment: .. so that explains why I was facing the same problems on SO. (can't link to my meta question, it's been deleted)