# Tag-editing doesn't have tag suggestions anymore?

Tags: support, tags, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag suggestions do not appear while inline editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98356/tag-suggestions-do-not-appear-while-inline-editing)

Is it just me or are other people not getting the tag-suggestion pop-up list when they use the edit tags feature?  (Specifically, I mean the one that appears when one has sufficient rep and hovers over the tags, as opposed to the one when composing<s>/editing</s> a question, which still works fine for me.)

***Edit*** Actually, it turns out that if I am in the in-place question editing as opposed to the separate-page-load question editing, I don't get tag suggestions either.

***Edit 2*** It looks like I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'` in tageditor.js at the moment that I click the edit tags button or the edit link (which loads the in-place post editor).

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? What browser and version are you using?

Comment: @random: Now I have, but still no luck.

Comment: @random: Chrome 13.0.782.99 beta on OS X 10.6.8.  It's also possible that this is localized to math.stackexchange.com and its meta, as I don't have sufficient rep to have this ability on any other site.

Comment: I used to have this problem intermittently - I can't seem to find my meta question :\

Comment: No repro in: the in-page *tag* editor; the in-page *post* editor; the ask question page. FF 5.0 on Win7 x64.